# NVD3 Line Chart not updating yAxis with forceY

Tags: angularjs, angular, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I have a line chart with a margin between the lowest and highest price and the chart borders. I don't want the ticks touching the top and the bottom of the chart, so I used forceY to achieve that.

```
<nvd3-line-chart
data="sample_data"
id="sample_data"
height="350"
showXAxis="true"
forcey="{{y_axis_range}}"
showYAxis="true">
</nvd3-line-chart>
```

The data:

```
sample_data: [
 { 
  key: "PRODUCT 1",
  values: [ [ 0, 10.0 ] ] 
 },
 { 
  key: "PRODUCT 2",
  values: [ [ 0, 9.0 ] ] 
 }
],
y_axis_range: [ 8.0, 12.0 ]
```

The thing is, when I change the data, the graph seems to redraw correctly. The yAxis ticks are updated with highest values, but **the values of the data, not the y_axis_range**.

> How to properly force the graph to have the tick range intended?

Comment: are maybe the values between two brackets? Maybe should be one bracket? `forcey="y_axis_range"`

Comment: It works this way. If I write without the brackets or with a single, it breaks.

Comment: It seems you have to embed the option in options object:  forceY: [100].

Go and read https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/issues/54.

I think the max should be a unique number, because the axis has only one max. There is not two y axis.

Comment: I'm trying to go somewhere from where he is pointing. Thanks for finding that out.

Comment: sure, you welcome! mark up-vote on comment if it was useful !

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz I don't know if it's my reputation of 1 or my ignorance as a first timer asking a question, but I can't seem to find how to do it. It indeed was useful, but I'm yet to solve the issue. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ok!! just hope you can finally solve ! Maybe if you post more of your code, with some other data, we will be able to help or improve!!